# Pythy Finite Ordinals

Tags: code-golf, code-generation, set-theory, pyth

Write a program in any language that takes a single natural number *n* as input and generates a [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) program that, in turn, produces, using nested lists, the nested set given by S(n), where:

> *S(0) = ∅*
>   *S(n+1) = S(n) ∪ {S(n)}*

<sup>S(n) giving the set representation of the corresponding [ordinal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).</sup>

Using the list representation required by this question, this gives (as the final output from the generated Pyth program):

```
0->[]
1->[[]]
2->[[],[[]]]
3->[[],[[]],[[],[[]]]]
```

Etc.

Again, the challenge is to write a program in another language for generating the corresponding Pyth program.

This is code golf, so shortest full program wins.

Comment: Are the spaces in the output optional?

Comment: The spaces in the final output (from the pyth program) are optional.

Comment: The generating program takes the input though, the generated result isn't allowed to take any.

Comment: It'd be trivial to append something like `J<input>` at the front.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <strike>11</strike> 10 bytes

```
"u+G]G"z\]
```

*"Answers must be at least 30 characters."*